# How to link custom framework within UITest target in Xcode - another "Library not loaded - @rpath"-issue

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, uitest, rpath

My project uses Xcode 11.3.1 and is structured as followed:

```
MyProject
 - MyProject.xcworkscapce
 - MyFramework 
 - MyApp
   -MyApp (main-target)
   -MyAppUITests (uiTest-target)
```

MyApp imports `MyFramework` and can be built und run just fine. For this to work I added `MyFramework` to main-target into main-targets **General/Frameworks and Libraries**.

In my UITest target I need to access some classes (Accessibility-Identifier-Definitions) from `MyFramework`, so I need to import these somehow.

Both targets are building and the main-target works without any issues. I am also able to run ui-tests on a simulator. Unfortunately I am forced to run my tests **on real devices**, and here **I get this runtime error**:

```
The bundle “MyAppUITests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.

(dlopen_preflight(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E581B3BA-A9A2-4AA3-A1BA-91C57DCD3846/MyAppUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/MyAppUITests.xctest/FHCommunityUITests): Library not loaded: @rpath/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework

  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/E581B3BA-A9A2-4AA3-A1BA-91C57DCD3846/MyAppUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/MyAppUITests.xctest/MyAppUITests
  Reason: image not found)
```

I am fairly new to this framework-thing (and also to ui-tests) and it's been two days I am dealing with this issue now. Most posts about similar issues are related to misspecified Podfiles, but in my barebone sample project which I setup to not destroy my real project I am not using any Pods. I tried probably all of the suggested solutions (and almost all combinations :() and none of them seem to work.

It took me a while to figure out that in my uiTest-target **build phases** I can actually add a **New Run Script Phase** and I assume I need to somehow link MyFramework here.
Is this correct? Can someone help me defining the run script?

And yes, I tried to clean my app (and I also deleted derived data).

Help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Ok, finally I figured it out. The solution is fairly simple and I haven't seen anyone suggesting this. Here we go:

To use your custom framework in your app target simply add it under `Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content`:

[image]

Now you can access MyFramework from the main target.
I could also run my ui-tests from the simulator, but still got the error described above when executing my ui-tests from my real devices.

To get rid of the `The bundle “xxxUITests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.`-Error I had to go to my **uiTest-target** and link the framework in my **build phases**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As **Destination** choose **Frameworks** and select the Framework you want to use in your uiTest-target.

Now you should be able to run your ui-Test from your device.

Comment: This answer is a buried gem! Thank you!

Comment: Yea, for me also this answer save my day. Thank you stranger!!!